# Path Variable In Custom URL Scheme Using Branch.io?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, url-scheme, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I'm having a problem for deeplinking in iOS when the user haven't installed the app. I can't use universal link because the link that's access by user will be a redirect link to the link that have the AASA file. The link that'll be clicked/accessed by user is **"deeplink.example.com/{input}"** which will redirect to **"api.example.com/api/v3/deeplink/{input}"**, so I can't use universal link, so that endpoint will redirect to URL Scheme instead, like **myApp://deeplink/{input}**.

I can't find a solution for this problem when user haven't installed the app while still using url scheme, so I'm thinking instead of redirecting it to url scheme, i'll put the url scheme in branch.io and redirect the endpoint to branch.io, like **branchdeeplink.com/{input}**.

The problem is, can I pass the the input in **branchdeeplink.com/{input}** to custom url scheme in **myApp://deeplink/{input}** using branch.io?

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

Passing in query param in the URI scheme as in the example shared is currently not possible. Since you can already attach custom data to your deep links we don't support query params for URI schemes. When you are creating your [links](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/create-quick-links) you can add

> $deeplink_path = product/123

Since Branch automatically appends URI scheme to your links, when the link would open your application like this -

> yourUriScheme://product/123

which you can use for in-app routing.

When the users don't have your app installed, they'd be routed to either App Store or the URL specified under iOS redirects in the Configuration Section of Branch Dashboard.

Comment: Does that mean you have to create a link for each product? If I take your example it will be a link with: $deeplink_path = product/124 another with $deeplink_path = product/125 and so on?